# Why do we need the following set to have an infinite set?

Tags: definition, infinity, axioms, peano-axioms

By Dedekind's definition:

> **Definition**: We say that some set $S$ is infinite if there exists an injection $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that $\operatorname{Im}(f)\neq S$ (or $f(S)\neq S)$.

Now, the book says the following:
*Infinite set exists if an only if a set $N$ with following properties exists:*

There is an element $1\in N$.

There is a transformation $\nu:N\rightarrow N$ (the successor function) for which the following holds:
\begin{align*}
&\nu \text{ is injective}\tag{i}\\
&1\notin\nu(N)\tag{ii}\\
&\text{If a subset } X\subseteq N \text{ contains $1$ and } \nu(X)\subseteq X \text{ then } X=N.\tag{iii}
\end{align*}

Now, my question is, why there would be no infinite set without the existence of theset $N$? Or is this something simmilar to the axiom of infinity (e.g. the inductive set) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity? Is this definition of an infinite set equivallent to the axiom? I'm quite unsure how I should interpret this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that each infinite set must contain a set isomorphic to the natural numbers (which basically is $N$ since those are the Peano axioms).

This can be seen by the given definition as follows: Let $S$ be an infinite set, and $f:S\to S$ the corresponding injective map for which $f(S) \neq S$.
Then there exists at least one element which we call, for simplicity, $1 \in S$, for which $1 \notin f(S)$. 
Now define the set
$$ N:= \{1, f(1), f(f(1)), f(f(f(1))), ... \}.$$
Can you see why this set $N$ satisfies the three properties, with $f$ being the successor function?

Comment: So basically, anything bigger than *finite* must contain the set $N$ as its subset, is that the idea? Then, if the set $N$ didn't exist, we wouldn't be able construct anything larger than *finite* sets. So for this, we have the axiom that such set exists (axiom of infinity) and the peano axioms which gives us the precise idea on how to construct this set $N$ which has to be contained in the infinite sets. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.